# Rails - acts_as_list with multiple Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I've managed to use `act_as_list` with my Models (it was quite easy) one by one, but now i have a problem.

In my app there are 3 models: `Facility`, `Service` and `Activity`. I need to use `acts_as_list` on their union... is it possible to do that?

Hope my question is clear

Answer (score 6):

You should use a fourth model with a polymorphic association, then put the list on that.

First, read up on polymorphic associations to understand this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Now you'll want to have a class that looks like this:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :positionable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And a migration that looks like this:

```
class CreatePositions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :position do |t|
      t.integer :positionable_id
      t.string  :positionable_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then on each of the other models add this:

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :position, as: :positionable
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Can you expand a little on the overall structure? Like have a Position model, with positionable_id. Then have the other three models have_one  , :as positionable?

Comment: fyi, ryan bates just had a railscast on the topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised

Comment: Hey Jeff, yeah I saw that. Got it all sorted and working well thanks!